# Zurb foundation reveal modal

Tags: zurb-foundation

I am using Zurb Foundation 6 framework and I want to use the reveal modal. For some reason there is no response when clicking the button to open the modal.

```
My JsFiddle
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zzf2suto/1/

Answer (score 0):

Your jquery script url is wrong, also close button in reveal has different syntax

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.4.3/css/foundation.min.css">
</head>
<body>
 
  <a href="#" data-open="myModal">Click Me For A Modal</a>

  <div id="myModal" class="reveal" data-reveal>
    <h2>Awesome. I have it.</h2>
    <p class="lead">Your couch.  It is mine.</p>
    <p>Im a cool paragraph that lives inside of an even cooler modal. Wins</p>
    <button class="close-button" data-close aria-label="Close modal" type="button">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
  </button>
  </div>
     
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.4.3/js/foundation.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.4.3/js/vendor/what-input.min.js"></script>
<script>$(document).foundation();</script>
</body>
</html>
```

[Correct reveal modal syntax](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/reveal.html)